# Не срабатывает Dependency Injection для web api контроллеров в MVC приложении

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, unity-container

Имеется ASP.NET MVC приложение, появилась необходимость добавить web api контроллеры вместе с DI конструктора.
  В части MVC DI корректно срабатывает, в части  API приложение падает с  исключением  "Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor". Если создаю api контроллер с конструктором без параметров,то все успешно работает.
   Для api контроллеров был создан webapiconfig. в котором создается IOC контейнер Unity и регистрируются зависимости.В файле Global.asax реализуется DI mvc  и DI web api.
 Подскажите, пожалуйста,как решить проблему: не работает DI для web api контроллеров в mvc 5 приложении .

### WebApiConfig.cs

```
    public static class WebApiConfig
{

    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        // внедрение зависимостей                 

        var container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<IUserService, UserService>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<IApplicationContext, ApplicationContext>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<ICalculationService, CalculationService>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<IUserService, UserService>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        config.DependencyResolver = new UnityResolver(container);

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );



    }

}
```

### Global.asax

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {

        // внедрение зависимостей
        NinjectModule userModule = new NinjectUserModule();
        NinjectModule calculationRepository = new NinjectCalculationRepositoryModule();
        NinjectModule calculationModule = new NinjectCalculationModule();
        NinjectModule unitOfWorkModule = new NinjectUnitOfWorkModule();
        NinjectApplicationContext appContext = new NinjectApplicationContext();
        var kernel = new StandardKernel(userModule, unitOfWorkModule, appContext,calculationRepository, calculationModule);
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel));
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));            
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);

    }
}
```

Comment: Ninject и Unity одновременно используются?

Comment: Да,Ninject в mvc части, unity в api.